# Best way to display sum of columns in child objects

Tags: angular

I have a collection of objects I'm retrieving from a web service, each with their own collection of children. each child in turn has zero or one grandchildren, something like this:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"bob", "children":[
    {"id":"17","grandchildren":{"id":122,"number":47,}, 
    {"id":"18","grandchildren":[]}, 
    {"id":"19","grandchildren":[{"id":123,"number":47.5,}]
    ], 
.
.
.
]
```

I have a service that reads the things and returns an Observable . This is all a bit new to me, but I believe this is effectively a stream of thing objects?

In the html template I can display basic properties easily enough for each item:

```
<li *ngFor="let thing of things">
    name: {{thing.name}}</a>
</li>
```

The tricky bit is that for each thing I need to display the sum of the "number" fields of all of it's grandchildren. I've tried a few very messy ways to get this done and failed, is there a nice angular way to do this?

====== EDIT ======

Thanks to Dragos Andrei and ilyas shabi, I've taken Dragos' awesome function and dropped it into a fork of Ilyas' superb StackBlitz template, keeping the pipe layout.

forked template is here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-56701060-2z543f

Comment: I think the best way is to create a Pipe that takes a thing like Input and iterates through its children ... and returns the total number of its grandChildren. do you try this before ?

Comment: @ilyasshabi I did have a go at it but ended up in a bit of a mess, I don't think I really understood how the pipes work. I might need to have another read of the documentation and try it again.

Comment: @ilyasshabi That's really cool and a great starting point, thanks! Unfortunately I've phrased the quesiton badly and what I'm after is the sum of the number fields of the greandchildren, not the count of them. I've updated my question to make this more obvious (note to self, never use "number" as an example field name!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about now?

```
  getNumberOfChildren(thing: {
    id?: string;
    children?: Array<{
      id?: string;
      grandchildren?: Array<{ id?: string; number?: number }>;
    }>;
  }) {
    return thing.children
      .filter(c => c.grandchildren && c.grandchildren.length > 0)
      .map(c => c.grandchildren.map(g => g.number).reduce((a, b) => a + b))
      .reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  }
```

Comment: That's exactly right, thank you! I've combined it with ilyas shabi's pipe code and really like the way it works now. I'm an old school c# programmer so this is all new to me, but I'm beginning to love it.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this help?

component.ts code:

```
getNumberOfChildren(thing: { id: number; children: any[] } ){
  return thing.children.filter(c=> !!c.grandchildren && c.grandchildren.length > 0).length;
}
```

component.html code:

```
<li *ngFor="let thing of things">
  name: {{thing.name}} {{getNumberOfChildren(thing)}}</a>
</li>
```

Off topic, I would suggest getting used to using trackBy in your *ngFor. You can read more about the phenomenon here: https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5

Comment: Wow, that looks really close - what I need is the sum of the number fields from each grandchildren (I'll edit the quesiton to explain that a bit better) so I'm guessing I'm going to need a reduce() on the end somewhere? This is all a bit new to me!

Comment: Love the trackBy thing BTW, that had completely passed me by! There are a lot of thing objects here with live updates that won't change much, so it should make a huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

I created a [project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-56701060-hvn2qn) on stackBlitz, you can edit the **things** object on app.component.ts file and see if this is what really you want.

Hope this works for you

Comment: That's great - I've combined this with Dragos Andrei's map and reduce code and have exactly what I want, thanks!